# Creating a Zoomable Tree Web page with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps-api-3, tree, maptiler

So I am trying to create a web page that is an image of a tree (like a tree of life kinda, but much smaller) that you can zoom to see a more detailed view of the branches and as you zoom Text and links that fixed to certain parts of the tree (like the end of a certain branch for example) come in to view. I know there is tiler apis like the Google Maps Api or MapTiler but I'm just not sure if these will work for what I am trying to do. What I am trying to do is make a user interface similar to OneZoom's (www.onezoom.org).

Thanks for the help. Cheers.

Comment: Maybe: [https://github.com/jrosindell/OneZoomOriginal](https://github.com/jrosindell/OneZoomOriginal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapTiler Desktop was used for rendering, for instance, [Disqus Universe](http://webrender.net/disqus-universe/). Is that what are you looking for?

Comment: Yes that is what I am looking to do, Thank you. But just to clarify; MapTiler Desktop was used to render the map, correct?

Comment: The graph was created using igraph, rendered into a map using MapTiler Desktop.